# Does Sanic have a 'url_for()' function (like in flask)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, sanic

I'm trying to port a simple flask app to sanic, working with the example for [sanic and jinja](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/examples/jinja_example.py).

Does sanic have a `url_for()` function like flask?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Sanic 0.3.1 adds support for [`url_for()`](http://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/routing.html#url-building-with-url-for):

```
url = app.url_for('post_handler', post_id=5, arg_one='one', arg_two='two')
```

<s>No.  Currently sanic's router is very basic and does not support lookups. You can review the short source code here:  https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/sanic/router.py</s>

Answer (score 2):

Now the sanic support `url_for` method

[resource code](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/sanic/sanic.py#L236)